# map did not return array when has an inner loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, ecmascript-6

```
const testTrue = sample.map((condition) => {
  return Object.values(objects).forEach(value => {
    return someFunc(condition.abc, value)
  })
});
```

sample is an array, why above code don't make testTrue become `[ true, false ]` ? I got undefined, is it because of forEach here?

This is working

```
const testTrue = sample.map((condition) => {
  return someFunc(condition.abc, value)
});
```

Comment: The value returned to the `forEach` callback is ignored. What were you trying to do there? Can you give an example of `condition` and `objects` and your expected output?

Comment: Can you also provide info on what will be present in `sample` array?

Comment: please post your someFunc definition and how you want the result

Answer (score 3):

Actually, [`Array#forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) doesn't return anything, if you take a look at the **[`Array#forEach()` MDN Specifictaion](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)** you can see that its `ReturnValue` is `undefined`.

And that's why the `map` call isn't returning any element, in your code:

```
const testTrue = sample.map((condition) => {
  return Object.values(objects).forEach(value => {
    //The following will be ignored
    return someFunc(condition.abc, value)
  })
});
```

The call to `return someFunc(condition.abc, value)` is useless and it is as if you weren't writing anything.

**Solution:**

You can change the `forEach()` with an [`Array#map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) call to return transformed elements of your array:

```
const testTrue = sample.map((condition) => {
  return Object.values(objects).map(value => {
    return someFunc(condition.abc, value)
  })
});
```

Comment: I got array within array using your solution.